# Identify sans-serif font in printed business card

Tags: font-identification

I want to update the design on a business card, but I don't know the font used in the brand name (UN/CUARTO DESIGN). See the business card below.

[image]

I tried using different websites for this purpose but did not succeed. Following is the text used with and without filtering.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks an awful lot like bog standard ITC Avant Garde. Maybe all those different websites were thrown off by the custom `/I` and `/A`.

Comment: @usr2564301, thanks! It certainly is similar. Nevertheless, the ``/N``, ``/G``, and the ``/O`` are notoriously wider. Also, the ``/C`` resembles more a circle in the font I am trying to identify.

Comment: @usr2564301, I should mention that the closest one I found in my system is [Tex Gyre Adventor](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/TeX-Gyre-Adventor) that is a replacement for ITC Avant Garde Gothic.

Comment: To my eyes, the A, C, I and G are all potentially custom drawn so maybe exclude them from the search. Also, have you tried putting the rest of the text from the card through font recognition? Looks like it might all be the same font.

Comment: @Westside, I just tried with the rest of the text. But none of the options have the same R.

Comment: Google>Dafont>Sans Serif Fonts (compare to the closest)

Comment: I also suspect it may be a custom design, and not a font as such. You may have to use something similar as other users have suggested, and customise the outlines yourself. Not everything is a font you can download.

Comment: I ran your sample through whatfontis.com and it came up with Code Pro Lowercase (https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/font-fabric/code-pro/lc/). Add the couple of edits to the "A" and I think you'd have it.

Comment: @GoofyMonkey, I also think this one is the font. If you add your comment as an answer I could accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A run through of your sample on www.whatfontis.com came up with [Code Pro Lowercase](http://myfonts.com/fonts/font-fabric/code-pro/lc). Use this for the base and edit the 'A' yourself manually, and you should be very close.

[image]